# Handling django form views using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I am looking for more elegant way to solve this problem. Say I have say two buttons `x`, `y` in `main.html`:

```
<input class= "btn-check", name = "options", id="x">
<label class="btn btn-lg btn-info", for="x">x</label>
    
<input class= "btn-check", name = "options", id="y">
<label class="btn btn-lg btn-success", for="y">y</label>
```

What I want to do is after the button is clicked, I will do something in python and so in django `views` I will create a view function for each of the buttons (my current implementation):

```
def funcX(request):
    booleanX = doSomethingforX()
    return JsonResponse({"success": booleanX})

def funcY(request):
    booleanY = doSomethingforY()
    return JsonResponse({"success": booleanY})
```

and the ajax calls would be:

```
$("[id='x']").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "{% url 'funcX' %}",           
        success: function(response){
            if(response.success == true){
                //Do something
            }
        }       
    })
});
```

The ajax call will be the same for button Y.

Now, I was wondering if it is possible to do this with forms?
Say the html becomes:

```
<form method="POST", class="form-group", id="post-form">
    <input type="submit", value="x", class= "btn-check", name = "options", id="x">
    <label class="btn btn-lg btn-info", for="x">x</label>

    <input type="submit", value="y", class= "btn-check", name = "options", id="y">
    <label class="btn btn-lg btn-success", for="y">y</label>

</form>
```

Then in django views I have a view for the `main.html`. This way it saves a lot of views written in django.

```
def main(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST["options"] == "x":
        booleanX = doSomethingforX()
        return JsonResponse({"success": booleanX})
    
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST["options"] == "y":
        booleanY = doSomethingforY()
        return JsonResponse({"success": booleanY)})
    return render(request, "main.html")
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to write the ajax calls to receive from `views` and get the `JsonResponse` return for X and Y respectively...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<form method="POST", class="form-group", id="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" class= "btn-check" name = "options" id="options_input">
        <button type="submit" id="x">X</button>
        <button type="submit" id="y">Y</button>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('#x').click(function(){
    $('#options_input').val("X")
})
$('#y').click(function(){
    $('#options_input').val("Y")
})


$('body').on('submit','#post-form',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "/url/",
    data: formData, 
    success: function(response){
    },
    error: function (response) {
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
})
```

});

VIEWS

```
def main(request):
   if request.method == "POST":
       submitted_type = request.POST.get("options")
       if submitted_type == "X":
         doSomethingforX()
         return JsonResponse({"success": X)})
       else:
         doSomethingforY()
         return JsonResponse({"success": Y)})
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, however doing so lose the "radio buttion" functionality as a group?I was following the bootstrap5 way of writing this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/#radio-toggle-buttons

Comment: It seems that using ajax to submit "checks-radio-group" do not submit any options, when I print `request.POST` in django views it only shows csrf token in the dictionary but without any `options`. But if I remove ajax as middleman it works...